# Note errors in Ernesto Lecuona's Suite Andalucía (aka Suite Espanol)?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

I am trying to learn Ernesto Lecuona's *Suite Andalucía*. A [review from Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/review/R36Z992BCSBTZM/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0793525152&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=283155&store=books) says that my edition has hundreds of note errors, and as I practice I hear some questionable notes.

Here's what I want to know: Assuming there really are note errors in my sheet music, how can I find and correct all of them? Is there a list somewhere? If not, how do I distinguish between an error and an odd but intended note?

Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hm. Hal Leonard is not often the best quality, and I wonder if this is an example. I actually have an old, old print of the piece "Andalucia" from *Suite Espagnola* published by Edward B. Marks in 1932, which I guess is impossible to get now. The Marks edition seems just like how Lecuona plays it on the "Lecuona Plays Lecuona" CD that I have, and the review in question says it's from the Marks plates. I have no problem at all with the Marks edition, so if it's really the same, it might be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are often mistakes and discrepancies in different editions.  The best way to determine if there are errors is often (unfortunately) just to listen to recordings and use a pencil to correct notes in your score.

If there is repetition or transposition of phrases you can compare those and it can make your life easier finding the right notes (e.g. are the intervals consistent when the phrase is modulated (although take care if the composer has deliberately decided to change intervals at different points in the piece).  Consider whether a written note makes sense in the key it's been printed in.  The Amazon review you link to suggests that there are bits

I find IMSLP to be a good resource for checking scores - it has photocopies of different editions of out-of-copyright music.  Provided that the piece is out of copyright in your country (read the disclaimer on the website) you can download the piece and use it for your own study.  [This particular version seems to be a transposition,](http://imslp.org/wiki/Andaluc%C3%ADa_(Lecuona,_Ernesto)) which may or may not be better than the Hal Leonard one!  Have a go at cross-referencing the two.  Good luck!